# How to set MDIParent property of Child form in nonMDI Class?

Tags: c#, mdi, mdichild

I am working on MDI app which have Child Forms. I have to show Child Window once a certain conditions is met.

I created a separate Class named  **clsDashbord** having method **loadDashboard()** which is supposed to load frmDashboard already designed. Code is given below:

```
 public void loadDashboard(String userName)
        {
            _Dashboard = new frmDashboard();
            _Main = new frmMDI();
           // _Dashboard.MdiParent = _Main;
            _Dashboard.Text = userName;
            _Dashboard.Show();

        }
```

Form does not show up if I set *MDIParent* to **Main** which is instance variable of MDI Form otherwise it gets displayed. How to do it?

Comment: Have you set `ismdicontainer` to true on the mainmdi form?

Comment: @ImmortalBlue yes I have. It does show other Forms.

Comment: _Main = new frmMDI();
         
           _Dashboard.MdiParent = _Main; **By Doing this it's not showing form otherwise doing it**

Comment: Is there any chance you can post a sample reproduction project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks more like a scoping problem by looking at line '_Main = new frmMDI();'

follow these steps:

1. create a class named 'ReferenceTable'
2. create a static variable named _Main in ReferenceTable
3. set ReferenceTable._Main = new frmMain(); // in Program.cs
4. set childform.Parent = ReferenceTable._Main //in all your child form
   code before calling Show() or showDialog() methods